# Best practice for distributing a nodejs command line application

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm, npm-install

How do people expect a nodejs commandline application to be organised when you distributed it via npm?

Would they expect to have to build it? Install it locally or globally? Should it always output a bin.js? Do you need some kind of alias / script to run it (via bin.js?).

Comment: Having written (and used) command line apps before the most common way people expect to be able to install it is via `npm install -g`. You just need to specify the 'bin' section in 'package.json'. There is no need to manually output a bin.js file.

Comment: Also, to avoid this question being closed you should rephrase it from "what's the best way to.." to "how do I..". The way it's phrased now imply you're looking to poll opinion - which is strongly discouraged on SO. Asking questions is fine, asking for opinion is not OK.

Comment: I want to know about industry convention, not just 'a way', or someone's favourite way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Use the `bin` field in `package.json` to specify the entrypoint javascript file for your CLI.
- Add `#!/usr/bin/env node` to the top of your entrypoint js file.
- Specify the files which need to be packaged with your app, using the `files` field of package.json
- In README, provide an `npm install` command line which a consumer can use to install your app, for example it could point at a github repository, or a package uploaded to the npm registry, which you can create with `npm pack`.

Upon installing the app locally or globally, a script will be created in the path (or locally in node_modules/.bin), which will let your command line app be run conveniently.